# What is the AFNetworking 2.0 Equivalent to cancel operations

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I used to be able to use `cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:` on the `AFHTTPClient` class to cancel operations. What is the new method to cancel operations?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can cancel operations manually. You can get the operations from the operation queue:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = // ...
for (NSOperation *operation in manager.operationQueue.operations) {
 // here you can check if this is an operation you want to cancel
    [operation cancel];
}

// or just cancel all of them!
[manager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

`AFURLSessionManager` also have an `operationQueue` property if you're more into `NSURLSession`.

Comment: RequestOperation is iOS 6+ & SessionManager is iOS 7+ afaik

Comment: Both of them work with the idea of operations. You just need to get them from the object you're using.